# System.exe explanation

Tags: windows-7, kernel

I see a process in task manager called "System", and I couldn't find any kind of relevant explanation about it on the net. Task manager shows its description to be "NT Kernel & System".  Could someone explain what is this process and how does it relate to the other core processes of windows 7?
Thanks!

Comment: Start Task Manager -> "Processes" tab-> click on View (menu) -> "Select Columns", select "Path to Image". And I see "NTOSKRNL.EXE" on my Win 7. Simply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Windows Internals 6th ed. Part 1. page 69

**System Process and System Threads**

The System process (process ID 4) is the home for a special kind of thread that runs only in kernel mode a kernel-mode system thread.  System threads have all the attributes and contexts of regular user-mode threads (such as a hardware context, priority, and so on) but are different in that they run only in kernel-mode executing code loaded in system space, whether that is in Ntoskrnl.exe or in any other loaded device driver.  In addition, system threads don't have a user process address space and hence must allocate any dynamic storage from operating system memory heaps, such as a paged or nonpaged pool.

Answer (score -1):

If the process is called System with PID of 4 then it is the "Web Deployment Agent Service"

If it's not with pid 4, occupying port 80 then it's just a part of the kernel handling the drivers that interact with the system hardware. Killing it will make your computer BSOD as well, as you experienced. I don't have any official microsoft reference right now, maybe someone could dig it up.

If the process is called System.exe:

Most likely it's a trojan backdoor + keylogger. I've had it in the past as well.

Here's a description from Kaspersky that should fit - hopefully. If it's not a variant of these viruses, still check the registry keys. I have added the description of PSW-Delf just so you can have a general guideline on how to remove it and handle the registry as well.

Before performing any manual checks I recommend downloading / updating antivirus + spyware/malware programs and running a full scan (boot scan, memory scan, file+registry scans).

Comment: -1, this seems unlikely and cursory Googling suggests that this is a legitimate process.

Comment: @cha0site can you provide a link if you downvote? Or refrain from downvoting unless we get a virus scan report from the poster?

Comment: Try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295714

Comment: @LonWolf The process is called "System", **NOT** "System.exe". And I don't have a file called "system.exe" anywhere on my system. If I terminate the process from task manager using "End process tree", I get a very nice BSOD (and WinDBG shows when I analyze the dump file that: `CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION (f4)
A process or thread crucial to system operation has unexpectedly exited or been
terminated.
Several processes and threads are necessary for the operation of the
system; when they are terminated (for any reason), the system can no
longer function.`) My initial question is still unanswered.

Comment: @johnye2e I added the explanation to "System" in case it's process ID is 4. Can you please check the PID of that process? if it's a reserved number, I can try to help more.

Comment: @LonWolf Yes, its PID is 4... but why is this "Web Deployment Agent Service" when I'm on a Win 7 x64 Ultimate edition?

Comment: @johnye2e maybe because you are running IIS or the Ultimate version of Win7 you are running has it configured and running already? The PC I am posting on has IIS enabled Win7 and I have it as well. Do a netstat to confirm you have port 80 occupied. Source that works on windows7 as well: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569087(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: It is also required for Visual Studio to do http solutions deployment using msdeploy

Comment: @LonWolf I don't have IIS installed (only IIS Express with VS 2010 Ultimate and VS 2012 Ultimate). 

Netstat:    `TCP    0.0.0.0:80        localhost:0       LISTENING`

Comment: @johnye2e msdeploy (or recently known as webdeploy) is included in the full visual studio bundles as well. I had to install it manually due to Express Versions. Most likely it got configured at install time specifically if you got the ultimate versions. If you can perform a web deploy from the visual studio IDE of a web application, then you already got it for sure. You can also check it's presence using the web platform installer.

Comment: @LonWolf Yes, I can perform a web deploy from VS, and yes, I found msdeploy here: "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3". In conclusion, System process has nothing to do with the core of Windows 7 (correct me if I got it wrong). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LonWolf: Removing downvote as you've fixed your answer, but please note accepted answer.

Comment: -1 because SYSTEM is not the "Web Deployment Agent Service". It's the kernel system thread container.